# Sum only if Previous > Current

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The problem I have having is that I would like to keeping summing up the values only if previous value is greater than my current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by use `groupby` , with `diff` and `cumsum` create the addtional key , then we just need `cumsum` the value by reverse order

```
df['finalvalue']=df.iloc[::-1,:].groupby([df.id,df.value.diff().lt(0).cumsum()]).value.cumsum()
df
Out[208]: 
                    timestamp       id  value  finalvalue
0 2019-11-04  14:00:10.432783  device1   3000        9000
1 2019-11-04  12:20:03.946156  device1   6000        6000
2 2019-11-04  11:19:03.946156  device1   1000        5000
3 2019-11-04  10:19:03.946156  device1   4000        4000
4 2019-11-04  09:19:03.946156  device2   1000        5000
5 2019-11-04  08:19:03.946156  device2   4000        4000
```